# Xamarin Forms Nullable Property - Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin Forms and trying to bind a nullable property in XAML  :

```
 public DateTime? LocalExpiryDate  //property on Person class
    {
        get { return GetValue<DateTime>(); }
        set { SetValue(value); }
    }

 <Label Text="{Binding LocalExpiryDate}"/>
```

And binding in the code behind as:

```
 InitializeComponent();
 MainStackLayout.BindingContext = member.Person;
```

Even though the property isn't null when I try and run the app on the Android Emulator I get an error "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation", and drilling down into the error I get a message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

If I remove the ? to make the property not nullable then the app works fine as long as there is a property

Is it not possible to bind to a nullable property or is there a way around this?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Is `LocalExpiryDate` a `BindableProperty` of your control?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding - I'm binding to the label with <Label Text="{Binding LocalExpiryDate}"/>

Comment: I'm wondering where have you declared `LocalExpiryDate`

Comment: LocalExpiryDate is a filled property of an entity called Person with data in it. Works fine if property isn't set to be nullable, but fails as soon as it's made nullable again

The other properties on the Person model bind fine

Comment: Could you post more info about `Person`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand your issue. I have `Page`:

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    private Person _person;
    public Person Person
    {
        get { return _person; }
        set
        {
            _person = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public Page1()
    {
        BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        Person = new Person() { Date = DateTime.Now };

        base.OnAppearing();
    }
}
```

I have `Person`:

```
public class Person : BindableObject
{
    private DateTime? _date;
    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set
        {
            _date = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And I have `XAML`:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CommonSample;assembly=CommonSample"
         x:Class="CommonSample.Page1">
  <StackLayout>
    <Label Text="{Binding Person.Date}"/>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: That's brilliant, BindableObject worked. Person was marked with  Breeze.Sharp.BaseEntity to use with Breeze Sharp, but changing to BindableObject  fixed it